# Exactness of sequence of vector spaces with tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, exact-sequence

Let
$k$
be a field and
$0\rightarrow
V
_n
\xrightarrow{f_n}
V_
{n
−
1}
\xrightarrow{f_{n−1}}
···
\xrightarrow{f_3}
V_
2
\xrightarrow{f_2}
V_
1
\xrightarrow{f_2}
V_
0
\rightarrow 0$
an exact sequence of finite-dimensional
$k$
-vector spaces.

Let
$V$
be a finite-dimensional
k
-vector space. 
Is the sequence

$0\rightarrow{V_n\otimes V}\xrightarrow{f_n\otimes 1_V}V_{n-1}\otimes V\xrightarrow{f_{n-1}\otimes 1_V}\cdots \xrightarrow{f_3\otimes 1_V}{V_2\otimes V}\xrightarrow{f_2\otimes 1V}V_1\otimes V\xrightarrow{f_0\otimes 1_V}V_0\otimes V\rightarrow 0$

necessarily exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every vector space is a '[flat module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module)'.